# Python union of sets raises TypeError

Tags: python, set, generator-expression, set-union

Consider a sequence of sets:

```
>>> [{n, 2*n} for n in range(5)]
[{0}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {8, 4}]
```

Passing them directly into the union method yields the correct result:

```
>>> set().union({0}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {8, 4})
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
```

But passing them as a list or generator expression results in a TypeError:

```
>>> set().union( [{n, 2*n} for n in range(5)] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

>>> set().union({n, 2*n} for n in range(5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Why does it happen and what are some solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `set.union()` expects one or more sets (ie `set.union(oneset, anotherset, andathirdone)`), not a `list` nor generator.

The solution is to unpack your list or generator:

```
>>> set().union( *({n, 2*n} for n in range(5)) )
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's way to union multiple sets without creating a list

```
s = set()

for n in range(5): 
    s = s.union({n, 2*n})
```

Comment: It does work indeed but that's far from being the most effective code (for range(10) it's about 50% slower than U9-Forward's solution).

Comment: @bruno fair enough, I was just adhering to the NO-LISTS rule he had made in a comment. :)