# TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that gives me the union of set A and B, but it is giving me the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

**Code:**

```
A = {1, {2}, 3}
B = {{1, {2}}, 3, 4}
A | B
```

What went wrong?

Comment: A set can not contain a set, since, like the error says, sets are unhashable. Only hashable elements can be added to a set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python union of sets raises TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871836/python-union-of-sets-raises-typeerror)

Comment: Note that the error occurs on line 1. So @tripleee the union is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

As @WilliemVanOnsem pointed out: [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) are mutable and not hashable and can not be included in other sets.

If you need hashable sets you can [use `frozensets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) - wich are *frozen* (immutable) and hence hashable:

```
A = {1, frozenset({2}), 3}
B = {frozenset({1, frozenset({2})}), 3, 4}
print(A | B)
```

Output:

```
set([1, 3, 4, frozenset([2]), frozenset([1, frozenset([2])])])
```