# set as dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I ran the below line of code in Python but got an error titled "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' ". I want to turn that key to a list.
How can I solve this error?

```
dictionary = {
    'a' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    'b' : 2,
    {100} : 3
}
print(dictionary['a'][1][2])
```

Comment: Related: [TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53143163/4518341), [Add list to set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1306631/4518341)

Answer (score 5):

keys of a dictionary must be hashable (or better: immutable). `set` objects are *mutable* (like lists)

you could use a `frozenset` instead

```
dictionary = {
    'a' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    'b' : 2,
    frozenset({100}) : 3
}
```

A [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) is a `set` that is immutable. It's a builtin type. Now you can get the value even by passing a frozenset made of lists/tuples with duplicate entries/any order in the list and it still finds the value

```
>>> dictionary[frozenset((100,100))]
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: hashable implies immutable, no?

Comment: What is frozenset mean?

Comment: you can create hashable objects that aren't immutable, by just implementing  `__hash__`. But that's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have `set` as a dict key. Keys must be hashable objects (you may interpret it as immutable). So you can use `tuple` instead:

```
dictionary = {'a': [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 'b': 2, (100,): 3}
```

Comment: Or how about `frozenset`?

Comment: That is fine also.

Comment: Thanks @RazmikMelikbekyan