# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using nltk.FreqDist on Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I am trying to get the word frequencies for terms within each tweet contained in a dataframe.

Using this code the tweets are all treated like one word:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import csv
import collections
from collections import Counter
nltk.download('stopwords')

data= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/leska/Desktop/tweets.csv.zip', compression='zip')

print (data.columns)
print (len(data.tweet_id))
tweets = data.text
sw= set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words ('english'))
punctuation = set (string.punctuation)
tweets_filtered = [w.lower() for w in tweets if w.lower() not in sw and w.lower() not in punctuation]
words = nltk.FreqDist(tweets_filtered)
print(len(words))
df_fdist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(words, orient='index')
df_fdist.columns = ['Frequency']
df_fdist.index.name = 'Term'
print(df_fdist)
df_fdist.to_csv('C:/Users/leska/Desktop/Tweets2.csv')
```

So I tried tokenizing the words within the text column of the dataframe so each word would be counted:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import collections
from collections import Counter
nltk.download('stopwords')
sw= set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words ('english'))
punctuation = set (string.punctuation)
data= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/leska/Desktop/tweets.csv.zip', compression='zip')

print (data.columns)
print (len(data.tweet_id))
tweets = data.text
test = pd.DataFrame(data)
test.column = ["text"]
# Exclude stopwords with Python's list comprehension and pandas.DataFrame.apply.
test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (sw)]))
print(test)
chirps = test.text
splitwords = [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(chirps) ) for chirps in chirps ]

tweets2 = pd.Series(splitwords)

words = nltk.FreqDist(tweets2)

print(len(words))
df_fdist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(words, orient='index')
df_fdist.columns = ['Frequency']
df_fdist.index.name = 'Term'
print(df_fdist)
df_fdist.to_csv('C:/Users/leska/Desktop/Tweets2.csv')
```

This gives me the following error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Here is the full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 32, in 
    words = nltk.FreqDist(tweets2)

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 108, in **init**
    Counter.**init**(self, samples)

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\collections__init__.py", line 568, in **init**
    self.update(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 146, in update
    super(FreqDist, self).update(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\collections__init__.py", line 655, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I am stumped as I have converted the list to a series.

In the end I need the word frequency for each tweet to save to a .csv file.

I am very new to using both Python and Pandas so I am stumped. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, not just the last line

Comment: `[ nltk.word_tokenize( str(chirps) ) for chirps in chirps ]` is not going to do what you think, you need to use a different variable name for iterating than what you're iterating over, e.g., `[ nltk.word_tokenize( str(c) ) for c in chirps ]`

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried using `code` [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(c) ) for c in chirps ] `code` and the error remained the same.

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933892/set-as-dictionary-key/59933935#59933935

Comment: @RazmikMelikbekyanI'm sorry,  I am not sure how I would implement that in my code, could you clarify?

Comment: What does `tweets2` look like before you pass it to `FreqDist`?

Comment: @G.Anderson that helped considerably! But now my issue is that the output shows each term and the frequency, rather than the frequency of terms within each tweet (I hope that makes sense). I also realized that I need to also add all my original data to the new .csv in addition to the frequency information for each tweet.

Comment: Given that the marked duplicate resolved the issue you opened this question for, I would recommend going through and trying on your own to resolve any new issues that arise and ask a new question with a [mcve] if you can't figure out the next step(s)

Comment: @G.Anderson I have been trying to solve them on my own. I am running out of time though so I don't think I'll be able to post a new question, unfortunately. Thanks for your help though.